# How to convert rotation matrix to quaternion

Tags: rotation, eigen, quaternions

Can I convert rotation matrix to quaternion?
I know how to convert quaternion to rotation matrix but I can't find way to do opposite that.
I can show you the code how to convert quaternion to rotation matrix as bellow.

Example(C++): `Quaterniond quat; MatrixXd t; t = quat.matrix();` 
I want to know way to convert rotation matrix to quaternion like this.

Comment: Make sure `t` is a `3x3` matrix (known at compile time) and just assign it to the quaternion: `quat = t;` or if necessary: `quat = Eigen::Matrix3d(t);`

Comment: Thank you your replying. Is this how to convert rotation matrix to quaternion?

Answer (score 3):

A numerically stable algorithm for converting a direction cosine matrix D into a quaternion q is as follows:

```
T = D(1,1) + D(2,2) + D(3,3)
M = max( D(1,1), D(2,2), D(3,3), T )
qmax = (1/2) * sqrt( 1 – T + 2*M )
if( M == D(1,1) )
        qx = qmax
        qy =  ( D(1,2) + D(2,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qz =  ( D(1,3) + D(3,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qw = ±( D(3,2) - D(2,3) ) / ( 4*qmax )
elseif( M == D(2,2) )
        qx =  ( D(1,2) + D(2,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qy = qmax
        qz =  ( D(2,3) + D(3,2) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qw = ±( D(1,3) - D(3,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
elseif( M == D(3,3) )
        qx =  ( D(1,3) + D(3,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qy =  ( D(2,3) + D(3,2) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qz = qmax
        qw = ±( D(1,3) - D(3,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
else
        qx = ±( D(3,2) - D(2,3) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qy = ±( D(1,3) - D(3,1) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qz = ±( D(2,1) - D(1,2) ) / ( 4*qmax )
        qw = qmax
endif
```

Note that there is a sign ambiguity inherent in quaternions.  The algorithm above arbitrarily picks the sign of the largest element qmax to be positive, but it is equally valid to pick this sign as negative (i.e., essentially flipping all of the signs of the result).  It is up to the user to determine which is the more appropriate selection based on the application.

The ± selection is made based on the quaternion convention you are using:

Choose + for Hamilton Left Chain Convention or JPL Right Chain Convention

Choose - for Hamilton Right Chain Convention or JPL Left Chain Convention

Hamilton Convention means the quaternion elements i, j, k behave in a right-handed manner for multiplication (like cross products):

```
 i * j = k , j * k = i , k * i = j
```

JPL Convention means the quaternion elements i, j, k behave in a left-handed manner for multiplication (negative of cross products):

```
 i * j = -k , j * k = -i , k * i = -j
```

Right Chain means the quaternion rotation operation on a vector has the unmodified quaternion on the right side:

```
 D * v1 = v2 = q^-1 * v1 * q
```

Left Chain means the quaternion rotation operation on a vector has the unmodified quaternion on the left side:

```
 D * v1 = v2 = q * v1 * q^-1
```

For completeness, here is the algorithm for the other direction, converting a quaternion to a direction cosine matrix:

```
 D = (qw^2 - dot(qv,qv))*I3 + 2*qv*qv^T ± 2*qw*Skew(qv)
```

where ^T means transpose (for outer product in that term) and

```
qv = [qx]
     [qy]
     [qz]

I3 = [1 0 0]
     [0 1 0]
     [0 0 1]

Skew(qv) = [  0 -qz  qy]
           [ qz   0 -qx]
           [-qy  qx   0]
```

Comment: There is a typo on this line: qw = ±( D(1,3) - D(3,1) ) / ( 4*qmax ) It should be qw = ±( D(2,1) - D(1,2) ) / ( 4*qmax )