# Determine quaternion from coordinate system rotated at origin (three new unit vectors given)

Tags: math, quaternions

I have a base coordinate system x, y, z. With identical origin a second ortogonal system b, n, t (binormal, normal, tangent) which is determined dynamically in an animation. An object is to be aligned with respect to this system.

How to determine the corresponding quaternion in the system x, y, z from the three normalized vectors b, n, t?

Some time ago I created a conversion with visualization for axis, angle and quaternion in both directions. However, this does not help with the problem of specifying three system unit vectors.

See description https://discourse.threejs.org/t/quaternion-axis-angle-visualization/1358

https://hofk.de/main/threejs/quaternion/quaternion_axisangle.html
[image: Quaternion - Axis, Angle Visualization]

see also the docs https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=qu#api/en/math/Quaternion

UPDATE:

The transformation from rotation matrix to quaternion has been published several times. See also link in my own solution below.

The conversion of a vector basis to a quaternion is not identical and I could not find a publication.

The solution described below is based on taking new basis as rotation of initial basis. From this you get very easily a rotation matrix ( in this case the transpose).

If one connects this now with the well-known transformation rotation matrix to quaternation one receives the correct algorithm.

Note especially the signs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert rotation matrix to quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734840/how-to-convert-rotation-matrix-to-quaternion)

Comment: See UPDATE in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution myself.

Based on
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm

I get the following algorithm. (JavaScript)

```
class Quaternion {

    setFromBasis( e1, e2, e3 ) {
        
        const   m11 = e1.x, m12 = e1.y, m13 = e1.z,
                m21 = e2.x, m22 = e2.y, m23 = e2.z,
                m31 = e3.x, m32 = e3.y, m33 = e3.z,
                trace = m11 + m22 + m33;
    
        if ( trace > 0 ) {
    
            const s = 0.5 / Math.sqrt( trace + 1.0 );
    
            this._w = 0.25 / s;
            this._x = -( m32 - m23 ) * s;
            this._y = -( m13 - m31 ) * s;
            this._z = -( m21 - m12 ) * s;
    
        } else if ( m11 > m22 && m11 > m33 ) {
    
            const s = 2.0 * Math.sqrt( 1.0 + m11 - m22 - m33 );
    
            this._w = ( m32 - m23 ) / s;
            this._x = -0.25 * s;
            this._y = -( m12 + m21 ) / s;
            this._z = -( m13 + m31 ) / s;
    
        } else if ( m22 > m33 ) {
    
            const s = 2.0 * Math.sqrt( 1.0 + m22 - m11 - m33 );
    
            this._w = ( m13 - m31 ) / s;
            this._x = -( m12 + m21 ) / s;
            this._y = -0.25 * s;
            this._z = -( m23 + m32 ) / s;
    
        } else {
    
            const s = 2.0 * Math.sqrt( 1.0 + m33 - m11 - m22 );
    
            this._w = ( m21 - m12 ) / s;
            this._x = -( m13 + m31 ) / s;
            this._y = -( m23 + m32 ) / s;
            this._z = -0.25 * s;
    
        }
        
        this._onChangeCallback();

        return this;

    }

}
```

There you can see the usage.
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/quaternion-method-setfrombasis-e1-e2-e3/27407